# Running Python Script using STAF (Software Testing Automation Framework)

Tags: python-2.7, staf

I want to run python script (test.py) using STAF using below command but getting Retrun code 1

```
H:\>STAF 192.168.252.81 process START SHELL COMMAND "python /opt/test/test.p
" PARAMS "3344" wait returnstdout
Response
--------
{
  Return Code: 1
  Key        : <None>
  Files      : [
    {
      Return Code: 0
      Data       :
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the remote machine is on `trust list`, then try it without "PARAMS" or hardcode the value inside your python script.